# Adding Jquery reference in Google Doc App scripts editor

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-editor

I want to add jquery library reference in google Doc App scripts editor.I was trying to paste entire jquery library code but it did not work due to many conflicts and showing error window is undefined.Is there any way to add library reference in google Doc App scripts editor?

Answer (score 0):

Please read [the documentation about including external libraries to GAS](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide?hl=fr-FR#jquery),

see also [this article](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html-service-best-practices?hl=es#load_data_asynchronously_not_in_templates) and note this comment : `All recent versions of the jQuery and jQuery UI libraries are compatible with Caja, but the libraries load faster if you use the versions that Google hosts.`

Comment: Your above answer I think will work on Html page and Html service combination.But my concern is that I want to use jquery functions on code.js file when I do this and running it is showing $ is undefined. I am failed to add jquery library in that. Any suggestions on that.